# HTMLElement focus() blocks execution

Tags: angular, typescript, event-handling

(the following code is typescript and I'm working on angular 5, but I believe it's not this the culprit, but prove me wrong!)

I have a simple input, which passes some event to the angular component

(**EDIT**: included the full component code)

```
<span class="__picker-container">
    <input type="text" #geoSearchBox (keypress)="keyPress($event)" (keyup)="searchTerms.next($event)" [placeholder]="placeholder" />
    <small *ngIf="isLoading">caricamento...</small>
    <div #pickerList class="__picker-list">
        <a href="javascript:;" *ngFor="let result of searchResults | async" (click)="select(result.id)">{{ result.name }} ({{ result.code }})</a>
    </div>
</span>
```

While `keyup` perform a simple search via rest displaying result in a input's sibling `UL`, I use `keypress` to check if, when the user is typing, some keyboard code are used.

In particular I'm searching for `keyDown` and `keyUp`, to cycle though the result. Look at the code:

```
keyPress(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    const pl = <HTMLDivElement>this.pickerList.nativeElement;
    if (event.key === 'ArrowUp' || event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
        if (pl.childElementCount > 0) {
            if (event.key === 'ArrowDown') {
                this.childNodeIndex = this.childNodeIndex++ < pl.childElementCount - 1 ? this.childNodeIndex++ : 0;
            } else if (event.key === 'ArrowUp') {
                this.childNodeIndex = this.childNodeIndex - 1 >= 0 ? this.childNodeIndex - 1 : pl.childElementCount - 1;
            }

            console.log(this.childNodeIndex);
            (<HTMLElement>pl.children[this.childNodeIndex]).focus();
        }
    }
}
```

For now all is pretty straightforward.

Now the strange behavior: after `focus()` is called, it correctly focus the html element, but blocks the execution: other keypress events are ignored.

If I remove the line

```
(<HTMLElement>pl.children[this.childNodeIndex]).focus();
```

console.log emit the correct values for every keystroke I send.

What's wrong with this code?

Thanks in advance
Valerio

Comment: What do you mean "blocks execution"? You stop receiving keypress events? Or nothing is being typed?

Comment: I doubt this is blocking execution. Probably it's just that the event listener doesn't receive events anymore.

Comment: What is `this.pickerList`? "it correctly focus the html element" how do you know that?

Comment: @ArmenVardanyan exactly, I didn't receive any more events.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer pickerList is the input's sibling element which show the result. In particular, it is a UL tag. Could you please elaborate "the event listener doesn't receive events anymore"? Seems you targeted the problem here!

Comment: Please post more of your html, so we at least understand on which element is `focus` called

Comment: In particular, post the hole "pickerlist" div

Comment: Sorry, can't be more concrete without more concrete information to work with. Can you please create a minimal reproduction in http://stackblitz.com?
You also didn't address why you think the focus is set correctly. Is the element by any chance created using `*ngFor`?

Comment: Updated the code to show the full component HTML.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes, elements are create via *ngFor

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer because the first element, when using arrowup/arrowdown is correctly focused. In fact, the :focus css on the relative a tag is set. Subsequent event are not called, and I checked it via the console log, which is triggered the first time and not anymore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the focus to the `<a href="...">` then that is the element that receives keyboard events, not the `<input>` anymore.

Adding the event handlers to the `<a href="...">` as well should fix it

```
<a href="javascript:;" *ngFor="let result of searchResults | async" (click)="select(result.id)"
    (keypress)="keyPress($event)" (keyup)="searchTerms.next($event)"
    >{{ result.name }} ({{ result.code }})</a>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is what I missed.